# specify execution order of seed files in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to add data to two tables courses and course_subjects tables with the predefined data(as I don't need to alter these tables content). course_subjects table refers to courses table for the column course_id .When executing the **rake db:seed** command following error occurs.

```
ActiveRecord::InvalidForeignKey: Mysql2::Error: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails
```

How can I specify to execute course.rb in seed first then course_subjects.
I have data in separate csv files

Answer (score 14, accepted):

How I do it is by making another folder under db called seeds and storing my files in there. This lets me separate out the seed data so its not to clumped together.

In the seeds.rb file I then place this load command and then run db:seed

```
load 'db/seeds/users.rb'
load 'db/seeds/couples.rb'
load 'db/seeds/user_couples.rb'
```

So in each folder I would recommend loading in the corresponding csv and uploading the data. Then for the tables that you need a foreign key to you should load those later and use rails to load the data objects you need in.

If you are still looking for an example of it you can see it in this [project](https://github.com/Salinn/phitau/tree/master/db).

Answer (score 0):

Check out this great gem, called [seedbank](https://github.com/james2m/seedbank).

Look on the example from the docks:

```
after "development:companies" do
  company = Company.find_by_name('Hatch')
  company.users.create(:first_name => 'James', :last_name => 'McCarthy')
end
```

You probably need to do something similar with Yours course_subjects:

```
after "development:subjects" do
  CourseSubject.create({ ... })
end
```

Answer (score 0):

My approach overrides rake db:seed and runs timestamped seed files under the seed directory in chronological order just like migrations.

In addition I include support for a "db/demo" folder so you can have seeds that are only for demo or one-off purposes and aren't part of the default load.

I've been seeding all of my projects this way for years and it works like a charm.

### Step 1: Setup Rake task

```
# lib/tasks/db.rake
desc 'Runs all seed files under seed folder'
task seed: :environment do
  Sample::Util::Data::Seeder.run!
end

desc 'Runs all demo files under demo folder'
task demo: :environment do
  Sample::Util::Data::Seeder.run!(include_demo: true)
end
```

### Step 2: Create a Seeder class

```
# lib/sample/util/data/seeder.rb
require 'fileutils'
require 'sample/util/data/seed_proxy'

module Sample::Util::Data::Seeder
  # this is the primary entry point into the Seeder responsible for running all of the seed files in each of the
  # registered GEMs and the host rails application. Unlike the migrator, it is not require to move each file into
  def self.run!(options={})


    # locate the paths for all seed files
    paths = Array(process_paths(options[:include_demo]))

    # fetch the full path names for each file
    files = Dir[*paths.map { |p| "#{p}/**/[0-9]*_*.rb" }]

    # load all of the current seeds and reference in an array
    loaded_seeds = Seed.select(:version).map {|r| r.version}

    seeds = files.map do |file|
      version, name, scope = file.scan(/([0-9]+)_([_a-z0-9]*)\.?([_a-z0-9]*)?.rb/).first
      name, version = name.camelize, version.to_i
      Thrive::Util::Data::SeedProxy.new(name, version, file)
    end

    # reorder the seeds to ensure they run in the correct order across all gems
    seeds = seeds.sort_by(&:version)

    puts "=> Seeding data"
    # process each seed determining first if they are eligible to be run.
    seeds.each do |seed|

      unless loaded_seeds.include?(seed[:version].to_s)
        start = Time.now
        puts "-- #{seed[:name]} (#{seed[:version]})"
        begin
          load seed[:filename]
          Seed.create(:version => seed[:version].to_s)
        rescue Exception => e
          puts e.message
        end
        diff = Time.now - start
        puts "   -> #{diff}s"
      end
    end

  end # def self.run

  # Determine the paths containing the seed files. Indicate if the
  # paths should include the demo files.
  def self.process_paths(include_demo=false)

    result = [File.join(Rails.root.to_s, "db", "seed")]
    result += [File.join(Rails.root.to_s, "db", "demo")] if include_demo

    result
  end # def self.process_paths

end # module Thrive::Util::Data::Seeder
```

### Step 3: Create a seed proxy

```
# lib/sample/util/data/seed_proxy.rb
class Sample::Util::Data::SeedProxy < $SeedProxyStruct ||= Struct.new(:name, :version, :filename)

  def initialize(name, version, filename)
    super
    @migration = nil
  end

end # class Sample::Util::Data::SeedProxy
```

### Step 4: Populate seed files

Place timestamped seed files under db/seed using the same format as you would for migrations such as

```
20170202200000_seed_tablename.rb
```

Inside this seed file, no class name is needed, you can jump straight into any statement you like.

### Step 5: run rake db:seed

You can also run `rake db:demo` to populate seed files under the demo directory.  This allows you to have a set of seed files that are required and an optional set that isn't intended for production such as dev/test data, demo/sample data, etc...
Voila!  Hope that works for you!